# Tutorial on how to use multirec

Tags: generics, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, multirec

I am writing a compiler in Haskell and need some tools to work with abstract syntax trees (like annotating them with source positions and other things). I have been pointed out to the [`multirec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multirec) package.

I have found some information about the package, but it is too dense to read and understand, as the ideas are presented from a theoretical point of view.

So I am looking for something more light, as tutorials or simple applications that illustrate the use of the package.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The primary documentation will be:

- the [haddock documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multirec/0.7.1/doc/html/Generics-MultiRec.html)
- [the Chalmers CS talk](http://www.andres-loeh.de/multirec-chalmers.pdf)
- the [ICFP paper](http://www.andres-loeh.de/Rec/MutualRec.pdf)

Comment: Your link named "Chalmers CS talk" is actually in Universiteit Utrecht!

Comment: Andres gave the talk at Chalmers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the pointers Don gave, there is also a [video of Andres presenting the paper](http://vimeo.com/6612724) at ICFP 2009 in Edinburgh.

In Chapter 6 of [Martijn van Steenbergen's Master thesis](http://martijn.van.steenbergen.nl/projects/Selections.pdf), Multirec is used for AST manipulation.